# SetValue for Dependency Property requires an object: How do I set the FontSizeProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Another way of asking this would be to say:

**"How do I set the value of an object to `24` so I can pass it as an argument to the `SetValue()`'s `value` parameter?"**

To be clear: *I'm just trying to set the value of a dependency property in the code behind*

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Foo {

  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();

      TextBlock1.Text = "bar";

      TextBlock1.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, 24);
    }
  }
}
```

When I **build** the app, it succeeds!

But when I **debug**, it throws an Argument Exception as shown here:

[image: Argument Exception because my value is not an object]

Why am I getting this error and/or how do I fix it?

Comment: Why would someone downvote my question and then not at least have the decency to leave a comment?

Comment: Why don't you just call `TextBlock1.FontSize = 24;`?

Comment: @Clemens - Because that's .NET code. I want XAML dependency properties because they give the application more functionality.

Comment: That makes no sense. `FontSize` is the CLR wrapper for the FontSize dependency property. Its setter directly calls `SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value)`. So with `TextBlock1.FontSize = 24` you are directly setting the dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens - I don't know. I'm just doing what I'm told. :D This information is current as of October, 2016.

Comment: Who's telling you that nonsense? Every dependency propery has a C# property wrapper. Application code is not supposed to call GetValue or SetValue directly. Start reading here: [Dependency Properties Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). By the way, `TextBlock1.Text ` is also a dependency property, where you don't call SetValue.

Comment: @Clemens - My instructor?

Comment: @Clemens - Read the first line of the document you just linked again but slowly. "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) provides a set of services that can be used to extend the functionality of a common language runtime (CLR) property."

Comment: Ask your instructor for an explanation why you should use the C# wrapper for the Text property, but call SetValue for the FontSize property. If he can explain that, you should look for a different instructor.

Comment: For your second comment, you have misunderstood what "extend" means. A dependency property should be get and set like any other other property.

Comment: He just said that it's an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: @Clemens - You mean 4th?

Comment: Sure, but not the recommended way. See the *Setting Properties in Code* section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview#setting-property-values

Comment: Okay well I'm just going to follow what my instructor says to do. Bye! :)

Comment: Sooner or later you will learn that too. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FontSize` expects a double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize(v=vs.110).aspx).

Just add ".0" at the end of your value to tell the compiler it's supposed to be a double:

```
TextBlock1.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, 24.0);
```

You can also use the "d" suffix:

```
TextBlock1.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, 24d);
```

As much as possible, you should use the strongly-typed property instead of the dependency property. This way, you can use implicit casting whenever possible, and the type errors will be caught at compilation time:

```
TextBlock1.FontSize = 24;
```

Behind the scenes the property will update the dependency property. So you get the exact same features, but with type-safety.

Comment: Haha! Wow! Thank you!

Comment: @ihodonald You may have a good reason to use directly the dependency property, but if not then it's better to directly assign the property `textBlock.FontSize`. It is strongly typed, so you'll catch this kind of error at compilation time

Comment: @KevinGosse You should mention that in your answer.

Comment: @Kevin_Gosse This code comes from [a course on Lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/NET-tutorials/Use-some-dependency-properties/518689/548001-4.html). Apparently, using dependency properties enables data binding, XAML styles, animation for storyboards, and the usage of control templates (I don't understand templates yet but I'm about to learn how to use them).

Comment: @ihodonald The `FontSize` property (like most properties on UI controls) is just a wrapper on the dependency property: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs,846   So by using it, you get the same features, but with the added type-safety.

Comment: @KevinGosse I was really more interested in learning how to set dependency properties than using the FontSizeProperty itself IRL. But you *did* give me the correct answer, so I will return to my course now. :) Thanks again!